# 'init(make:update:attachments:)' is unavailable in visionOS

Tags: visionos

I am learning to use `RealityView`, and I will encounter an error when using `attachments`: **'init(make:update:attachments:)' is unavailable in visionOS**

```swift
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct MoonOrbit: View {
    var body: some View {
        RealityView{ content, attachments in
            async let earth = ModelEntity(named: "Earth")
            if let earth = try? await earth{
                content.add(earth)
            }
        } attachments: {
            Text("Earth")
                .tag("earth_label")
        }
    }
}
```

I checked the interface documentation and everything is fine.

[image]

It's frustrating and makes me unable to continue.

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/736588), but I really didn't notice any difference the first time

Old:

```swift
RealityView { content, attachments in
    content.add(Entity())
} attachments: {
    Text("Hello")
}
```

New:

```swift
RealityView { content, attachments in
    content.add(Entity())
} attachments: {
    Attachment(id: "h1") {
        Text("Hello")
    }
}
```

Finally, I found that in the `attachments` method, I also need to use `Attachment` to nest it.

[image]